# How to deserialize bytes, received in Java from Google protobuf?

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am trying to deserialize the google protobuf messages received from ZeroMQ and trying to convert to a JSON format, using the below piece of code. But in the final output, the fields, defined as bytes, are unreadable.

> ( for example, `"source_id": "\u0000PV\uff98t\uff9e"`).

Since it is a machine generated data we don't have the actual value sent from the source.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( message.getBytes() );
Schema.nb_event data = Schema.nb_event.parseFrom( is );
String jsonFormat = JsonFormat.printToString( data );
```

Output

```
{ "seq": 6479250, "timestamp": 1488461706,"op": "OP_UPDATE","topic_seq": 595736,"source_id": "\u0000PV\uff98t\uff9e","location": {"sta_eth_mac": {"addr": "xxxxxxx"},"sta_location_x": 879.11456,"sta_location_y": 945.0676,"error_level": 1220,"associated": true,"campus_id": "\uff9f\uff94\uffc7\uffa3\uffa2\b6\uffe3\uff92U\uff9f\uffdcN\'MT","building_id": "\uffee\u0016??X}5\u001a\uffaa\uffc4^\uffa0n\uffa4\ufffb\'","floor_id": "\uffd9/\"uF\uffdd3\uffdd\uff96\u0015\uff83~\u0005\uff8a(\uffd0","hashed_sta_eth_mac": "\u0013h\u0017\uffd0\uffef\uffc8\u001f\u0005V\u0010w?xxxxxx","loc_algorithm": "ALGORITHM_LOW_DENSITY","unit": "FEET"}}
```

==

```
{ "seq":          6479250,
  "timestamp": 1488461706,
  "op":                  "OP_UPDATE",
  "topic_seq":     595736,
  "source_id":           "\u0000PV\uff98t\uff9e",
  "location":          { "sta_eth_mac":          { "addr": "\uffc0\uffcc\ufff8P\uffee." },
                         "sta_location_x":    879.11456,
                         "sta_location_y":    945.0676,
                         "error_level":      1220,
                         "associated":            true,
                         "campus_id":            "\uff9f\uff94\uffc7\uffa3\uffa2\b6\uffe3\uff92U\uff9f\uffdcN\'MT",
                         "building_id":          "\uffee\u0016??X}5\u001a\uffaa\uffc4^\uffa0n\uffa4\ufffb\'",
                         "floor_id":             "\uffd9/\"uF\uffdd3\uffdd\uff96\u0015\uff83~\u0005\uff8a(\uffd0",
                         "hashed_sta_eth_mac":   "\u0013h\u0017\uffd0\uffef\uffc8\u001f\u0005V\u0010w?\uff88\uffa8\uffee\u000fm.\u0015\uffe9",
                         "loc_algorithm":        "ALGORITHM_LOW_DENSITY",
                         "unit":                 "FEET"
                         }
  }
```

All the unreadable fields are defined as bytes in the **`.proto`** file.
**Is there any additional step required to get these values?**

```
    optional bytes building_id        = 10;
    optional bytes floor_id           = 11;
    optional bytes hashed_sta_eth_mac = 12;
```

Comment: Well yes, that's opaque binary data. Why would you expect to be able to read it as text? Basically in Java they'd be a `byte[]`. Admittedly I'd expect the JSON formatter to convert them into base64 rather than the format you've shown, but it still wouldn't be readable text.

Comment: Indeed, the normal `JsonFormat` really should be serializing the bytes as Base64: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/34a1b6e6b8c0d477504d09df4df4b86770e47872/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java#L992 Is that the `JsonFormat` class you're using, or is this something else? (As an aside, is `mesage` a `String` or something else? If it is, calling `getBytes()` like that is a bad idea.) Fundamentally, a [mcve] would make it easier to help you.

Comment: The requirement is to deserialize the data and write as plain text in JSON format in our data lake. Is there a work around to get the actual value?

Comment: I am using com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat

Comment: After changing the JSON formatter to com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
I am getting the following output. But still not clear text.

Comment: "campusId": "n5THo6IINuOSVZ/cTidNVA==",
    "buildingId": "7hY/jVh9NRqqxF6gbqT7Jw==",
    "floorId": "LV/ZiQRQMS2wwKiKTvYNBQ==",
    "hashedStaEthMac": "a5elF6VJR7R0E7P2b6DpL4IDuxU=",

Comment: Right, that's base64, as I suspected. Fundamentally, the message has those values typed as `bytes` rather than as `string`. If they're meant to be text, why aren't they `string`? Protobuf is doing exactly the right thing here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Exactly.. what is the best option to get the text value from it now? Any way we can get this through the same json object?

Comment: It's not text. It's bytes. Do those bytes represent UTF-8-encoded text? If so, you need to decode them as you would any other bytes - the fact that you've got them through protobuf is irrelevant. It does sound like the fields in the message really should be text though - why are they not?

Comment: @JonSkeet This message is received from network controllers and the schema is defined by the vendor Aruba. http://www.arubanetworks.com/assets/ds/DS_ALE.pdf

Comment: So do you have any indication that these fields described as `bytes` really *are* encoded text? They could just be arbitrary binary data as far as I can see...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes all the fields declared as bytes are encoded in the output. I have a HTTP API for the same data where I can the values in clear text.

Comment: So you should include in the question what the values are as text and what the equivalent `bytes` fields have as their values. Those base64 values don't look like encoded text to me.

Comment: **Have you asked Aruba Tech Support directly, to provide** reference to their detailed **documentation on encoding / wrapping rules and practices?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON formatter `com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat` was returning as bytes but I was able to get in the required format base64 string after changing the JSON formatter to `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat`.